# How to add Chrome-like time remaining text to download notification

Tags: android, google-chrome, kotlin, notifications

How can i add this remaining time to download notification on Android Studio with Kotlin?

[image: chrome notification]

Answer (score 0):

A function such as that is usually implemented using a Service or a Worker.

There is a Background task that is downloading the file, and posting a new notification every second.

The "7 mins left" text is the subtext for a notification that is using the Progress Style.

I'm not really sure about the exact naming, but "1GB.zip" is the title, and "331.71 MB / 1.00 GB" is the text of the notifcation.